# working with xib files without autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xib, ios-autolayout

I have to support a existing project , in which the layout is set without autolayout. I have started ios programming working with autolayout.

I am not having any idea on how to set layout in xib files without auto layout.
If you know any tutorial, please share it. thanks

Comment: I would recommend taking the time to update everything to use AutoLayout. It will be much more maintainable.

Comment: Your code must be using AutoResizing, you can use autoresizing in your xib too. Because Project without autolayout or autoresizing cannot give compatibility in different devices.